# Android kotlin ArrayList.add agrega la referencia al objeto y no el valor. Por que?

Tags: kotlin

Uso las siguientes clases:

```
data class Recorrido(
    var fecha: Fecha,
    var comentarios: String
)


data class Fecha(
    var dia: Int,
    var mes: Int,
    var ano: Int
)
```

En Activity:

....

```
    var eventos = ArrayList<Recorrido>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alta_trayectorias)

    val fechita = Fecha(0,0,0)
    var evento = Recorrido(fechita, "")
    var fechaOk = false
```

.....

Cuando hago:
        evento.fecha.dia = 1
        evento.fecha.mes = 4
        evento.fecha.ano = 2019
        evento.comentarios = "Primer dato"

```
    eventos.add(evento)    //queda agregado, 1 4 2019 Primer dato

    evento.fecha.dia = 2
    evento.fecha.mes = 4
    evento.fecha.ano = 2019
    evento.comentarios = "Segundo dato"

    eventos    // muestra ahora 2 4 2019 Segundo dato
```

// Si ahora realizo el add

```
    eventos.add(eventos)    // tengo dos datos iguales correspondientes a 2 4 2019 Segundo dato
```

Por que pasa esto, como lo soluciono?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Disculpen la forma, no salio de forma clara, es mi primer pregunta.

Comment: Hola, tu ejemplo no es muy claro pero me parece que te falta evento = Recorrido(fechita, "") antes de agregar el segundo evento, y en eventos no deberia de ser eventos.add(evento) ? lo tienes como eventos.add(eventoS)

Comment: Rogelio, gracias por tus indicaciones, al final lo entendí, el problema es que las variables tipo objeto siempre se pasan por referencia y agrego 3 veces un objeto con valores distintos, en realidad agrego las tres veces la referencia al objeto por lo tanto todas las instancias mostraran los valores del mismo objeto, valores que serán los últimos asignados al mismo.   Desde ya muchas gracias